# Create a raster from points (gpd.geodataframe object) in Python 3.6

Tags: python, raster, geopandas, rasterio

I want to **create a raster file (.tif) from a points file** using a `geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame` object.

My dataframe has two columns: [geometry] and [Value]. The goal is to make a *10m resolution raster* in **[geometry]** point with the **[Value]** value.

My dataset is:

```
geometry |  Value
0  | POINT (520595.000 5720335.000) | 536.678345
1  | POINT (520605.000 5720335.000) | 637.052185
2  | POINT (520615.000 5720335.000) | 1230.553955
3  | POINT (520625.000 5720335.000) | 944.970642
4  | POINT (520635.000 5720335.000) | 1094.613281
5  | POINT (520645.000 5720335.000) | 1123.185181
6  | POINT (520655.000 5720335.000) | 849.37634
7  | POINT (520665.000 5720335.000) | 1333.459839
8  | POINT (520675.000 5720335.000) | 492.866608
9  | POINT (520685.000 5720335.000) | 960.957214
10 | POINT (520695.000 5720335.000) | 539.401978
11 | POINT (520705.000 5720335.000) | 573.015625
12 | POINT (520715.000 5720335.000) | 970.386536
13 | POINT (520725.000 5720335.000) | 390.315094
14 | POINT (520735.000 5720335.000) | 642.036865
```

I have tried before and so, I know that with `from geocube.api.core import make_geocube` I could do it, but due to some libraries I have a limitation and  I cannot use `make_geocube`.
Any idea?

Comment: Please post the data as text instead of as an image.

Comment: What do you mean by raster? Are you trying to plot an image? Save a GeoTiff?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, I want to save as as tif (.tif). Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign x and y columns, convert to xarray, then export to tiff using [rioxarray](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/):

```py
# do this before sending to xarray
# to ensure extension is loaded
import rioxarray

# assuming your GeoDataFrame is called `gdf`
gdf["x"] = gdf.x
gdf["y"] = gdf.y

da = (
    gdf.set_index(["y", "x"])
    .Value
    .to_xarray()
)

da.rio.to_raster("myfile.tif")
```

In order for this to work, the points must make up a full regular grid, with values of x and y each repeated for each combination. If this is instead just a collection of arbitrary points converting to xarray with x and y as perpendicular dimensions will explode your memory and the result will be almost entirely NaNs.

Comment: Had to use `gdf['geometry'].x` and `gdf['geometry'].y`

Comment: Thanks for this (+1). Would like to add that including `.rio.set_crs(gdf.crs)` before the call to `.rio.to_raster` will give the exported dataset the same projection information as your geodataframe.